# Force inline css for modifications in Dreamweaver CS4/5/6

Tags: css, automation, dreamweaver

In dreamweaver CS4 and more, when you change the format of some part of a text, particulary when this formatting touches a css aspect (like the size of the font in pixels, that is only available in the CSS properties panel and not the HTML one), Dreamweaver always tries to create a css class. Sometimes, it even change the base css style that is used for the part of the text you have changed.

I am very annoyed with this feature. You can force Dreamweaver to use the inline  method to make the formatting, that force it to be local, but you need to select this option each time. Just forget once, and you can "explode" your site formatting with unwanted modifications done by Dreamweaver in you css files.

So I would like to force Dreamweaver to ALWAYS use this inline  method to make the formatting instead of trying each time to create/update a css style, and I would take care of myself modifying the real base css style if I really need. And I don't, really don't want to select each time the "inline" option in the css pannel for each modification I do.

Do you how I may do ?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question like you were asking it to a 7 year old child, probably with some screenshots?